# Distance matrix hyperbolic space

Tags: linear-algebra, hyperbolic-geometry

I would like to do what I usually do in an euclidean space: create a distance matrix. This time I would like to have my multidimensional data in a hyperbolic space and then to create a distance matrix. Could you please please help me to understand how to it? My input data is a matrix with multidimensional vector. 
Thank you.

Comment: It is totally unclear what are you asking about. Are you asking how to compute distances between points in hyperbolic space whose coordinates are given to you? For that you can find several formulae on Wikipedia depending on which model you are working with.

Comment: The crux of your problem, as @MoisheCohen points out, is knowing which hyperbolic space your data is assumed to exist in.  "My input data is a matrix with multidimensional vector[s]" does not immediately suggest what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful to you, as it gives translation matrices in hyperbolic space along "principal axes":

[A dis­cus­sion of matri­ces for hyper­bolic geom­e­try](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/luther/blog/posts/29.html)

You might want to think a bit about which model of hyperbolic geometry you'd like to work with. The above discussion gives matrices in [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space), which is nice because the matrices look similar to those for Euclidean transformations.

The paper [Non-euclidean virtual reality I: explorations of H^3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.04004) gives matrices that work in the hyperboloid model in Minkowski space for arbitrary directions (but in small steps).

But depending on your goals, another model of hyperbolic space like the [Poincaré ball model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) might be preferable.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. I would like to use the Poincaré model. How can I use my n-dimensional data in this model?

Comment: So is your data a vector inside an n-ball, representing a point in H^n? It may be easiest to transfer between the ball and hyperboloid models, doing the translations in the latter. Going between the ball and the hyperboloid uses stereographic projection formulas.  Btw, I edited my answer to add another good reference.

Comment: Thanks. My data are raw data from a table without any transformation. My goal would be to put all these n-dimensional vectors in a hyperbolic space using the Poincaré model and then to measure the distance between these vectors into the hyperbolic space. What should be the step to do?

Comment: ah, so maybe you don't need a translation matrix at all, and just need a formula for the [distance between points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Distance). As for converting your n-dimensional vectors to the ball, I can't answer that question without knowing more about those vectors.  If they are represented in hyperbolic space in some way, they must already be in some model. (It doesn't make sense to take Euclidean vectors and interpret them as living in hyperbolic space.)

Comment: I second the suggestion to use the hyperboloid model. It is much more convenient and natural for all operations on the hyperbolic plane than Poincaré ball. I recommend using Poincaré for visual presentation only, and hyperboloid for internal calculations.